# Firestore filtering on both collection and his documents' subcollection

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible in Google Firestore to query a collection then filter it down on subcollection values?

I mean I got this data structure:

```
/
| repo/
| - title: title,
| - journal: Nyt,
| | category/
| | - name: News
```

I tried to query this way (e.g. to retrieve all articles of Nyt categorized news):

```
db.collection('repo')
  .where('journal', '==', 'Nyt')
  .collection('category')
  .where('name', '==', 'News')
```

but `'Query' object has no attribute 'collection'`.

I tried to structure data this way also:

```
/
| repo/
| - title: title,
| - journal: Nyt,
| - category: [
| | - news: News,
| | - tech: Tech,
```

and then query by `db.col('repo')....where('category.news', '==', 'News')` but unfortunately I also need to order_by other fields so Firestore ask to build indexes for every category in db...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Firestore.  You can only filter on values in a single collection or subcollection at a time.

You might want to consider copying the value of `journal` into the documents of each `category` subcollection so that you can perform a compound query on just the subcollection using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: Unfortunately I'd have to duplicate far more than the only "journal" property inside the subcollection...

Comment: It sounds like you need to restructure your collections in order to support the queries you want to perform.  What you have now simply isn't going to work, given the way Firestore supports massively scalable datasets.